# some information in the kaa-node.log

Tags: kaa

I am trying the Kaa server and I found some message in kaa-node.log file.
I am not sure these message will impact Kaa server's working normally or not.

1. the "Failed to lookup GLOBAL actor for endpoint" in the log file.

ex:
2016-10-30 23:56:10,582 [EPS-core-dispatcher-11] WARN  o.k.k.s.o.s.a.a.c.ApplicationActor - [[90, 73, -91, -2, 123, 48, 26, -63, 92, 70, 22, 116, -14, 54, -122, 115, 83, -83, 61, -86]] Failed to lookup GLOBAL actor for endpoint.

Although the message in the log file, but it seems the Kaa server still work normally.

---

2. org.kaaproject.kaa.server.common.dao.exception.DatabaseProcessingException: Endpoint profile is not subscribed to this topic
   (attach the message like below code sample block)

This message seems happen while sending unicast notification to some endpoints, but these endpoints don't subscribe to this topic.
I also found the CPU loading will add from 8% to about 55% after these message happen.
Although Kaa server seems work normally, but the CPU loading seems keep on 50-60%.

Have anyone know the meaning of above message??
And have anyway to low the CPU loading after the 2nd message appear.

```
org.kaaproject.kaa.server.common.dao.exception.DatabaseProcessingException: Endpoint profile is not subscribed to this topic
at org.kaaproject.kaa.server.common.dao.service.NotificationServiceImpl.saveUnicastNotification(NotificationServiceImpl.java:284) ~[dao-0.9.0.jar:na]
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor82.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:302) ~[spring-aop-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190) ~[spring-aop-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) ~[spring-aop-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) ~[spring-tx-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281) ~[spring-tx-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-tx-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208) ~[spring-aop-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy81.saveUnicastNotification(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at org.kaaproject.kaa.server.control.service.DefaultControlService.editUnicastNotification(DefaultControlService.java:1400) ~[kaa-node-0.9.0.jar:na]
at org.kaaproject.kaa.server.admin.services.KaaAdminServiceImpl.sendUnicastNotification(KaaAdminServiceImpl.java:2580) ~[kaa-node-0.9.0.jar:na]
at org.kaaproject.kaa.server.admin.controller.KaaAdminController.sendUnicastNotification(KaaAdminController.java:2285) [kaa-node-0.9.0.jar:na]
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor80.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221) [spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136) [spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110) [spring-webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:817) [spring-webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:731) [spring-webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) [spring-webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959) [spring-webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893) [spring-webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:968) [spring-webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:870) [spring-webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:755) [gwt-user-2.7.0.jar:na]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:844) [spring-webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848) [gwt-user-2.7.0.jar:na]
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:769) [jetty-servlet-9.2.2.v20140723.jar:9.2.2.v20140723]
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1667) [jetty-servlet-9.2.2.v20140723.jar:9.2.2.v20140723]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118) [spring-security-web-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84) [spring-security-web-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113) [spring-security-web-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103) [spring-security-web-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113) [spring-security-web-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154) [spring-security-web-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45) [spring-security-web-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:201) [spring-security-web-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50) [spring-security-web-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87) [spring-security-web-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192) [spring-security-web-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160) [spring-security-web-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346) [spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262) [spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1650) [jetty-servlet-9.2.2.v20140723.jar:9.2.2.v20140723]
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:583) [jetty-servlet-9.2.2.v20140723.jar:9.2.2.v20140723]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143) [jetty-server-9.2.2.v20140723.jar:9.2.2.v20140723]
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:577) [jetty-security-9.2.2.v20140723.jar:9.2.2.v20140723]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223) [jetty-server-9.2.2.v20140723.jar:9.2.2.v20140723]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1125) [jetty-server-9.2.2.v20140723.jar:9.2.2.v20140723]
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515) [jetty-servlet-9.2.2.v20140723.jar:9.2.2.v20140723]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185) [jetty-server-9.2.2.v20140723.jar:9.2.2.v20140723]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1059) [jetty-server-9.2.2.v20140723.jar:9.2.2.v20140723]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141) [jetty-server-9.2.2.v20140723.jar:9.2.2.v20140723]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97) [jetty-server-9.2.2.v20140723.jar:9.2.2.v20140723]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:485) [jetty-server-9.2.2.v20140723.jar:9.2.2.v20140723]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:290) [jetty-server-9.2.2.v20140723.jar:9.2.2.v20140723]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:248) [jetty-server-9.2.2.v20140723.jar:9.2.2.v20140723]
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540) [jetty-io-9.2.2.v20140723.jar:9.2.2.v20140723]
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:606) [jetty-util-9.2.2.v20140723.jar:9.2.2.v20140723]
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:535) [jetty-util-9.2.2.v20140723.jar:9.2.2.v20140723]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_60]
```

Comment: When did you get the first message about GLOBAL actor?  The second message is expected - Kaa server threw exception cause you  sent an unicast notification to EP which not subscribed to this topic and thus prevent unacceptable operation. Also, I did observe any increase in CPU load after this exception.

Comment: We got the global actor message when the Kaa server start.

Comment: Do you try to connect EP to Kaa server during startup? This exception can be caused by that Global Actor had not been instantiated yet and EP failed to look up one.

Comment: Yes, we try to connect EP to Kaa server during startup. Because we ever restart server and EP try to reconnect to server during server startup. EP should connect to Kaa server after server start complete. But, this message still appear.

Comment: In this case, this message doesn't say that system is working inappropriately just failed to look up GLOBAL actor, it will try again to look up and finally, EP connected to Kaa server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I write in comments above:

The first message doesn't say that system is working inappropriately just failed to look up GLOBAL actor, it will try again to look up. Finally, EP will connect to Kaa server.

The second message is expected – Kaa server threw exception cause you sent an unicast notification to EP which not subscribed to this topic and thus prevent unacceptable operation. Also, I did observe any increase in CPU load after this exception.